# Problems with Vim and lua?

Tags: vim, github, lua, terminal, neocomplete

I installed yadr onto my terminal, but I keep getting the following error when I open Vim:

```
neocomplete does not work this version of Vim.
It requires "if_lua" enabled Vim(7.3.885 or above).
```

EDIT:

- Upgraded Vim to version 7.4.493 but still get the error.
- Running OS X Yosemite

Comment: YADR, the last thing people who don't know how to update programs on their computer need. What about telling us **what OS you are using and how you installed Vim — if you did?**

Comment: I have been using YADR for a long time on my MacBook Pro. I fixed this same problem on my MBP half a year ago but I just don't remember how to fix it anymore... I got my Vim to update, but I might need to recompile Vim with lua... Not sure.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**This fixed it:**

```
brew install macvim --with-cscope --with-lua --HEAD
brew uninstall vim
brew install vim --with-lua
```

**If it still doesn't work after running the previous commands:**

When you install `vim` with `brew`, it probably didn't install it to the "correct" location. Looking at the terminal output during the installation (`brew install vim`) should tell you this location. For me, `brew` installed `vim` here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.712
```

Whereas when I ran `which vim`, I got the following result:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

So all you have to do is:

```
sudo cp /path/to/newly/installed/vim /path/to/old/vim
```

In my case, I did:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.712 /usr/bin/vim
```

Comment: Perfect, please mark this a the accepted answer (even though it's yours). One note for others. The 'vi' alias will probably still point to the system version of vim, so be sure to use the 'vim' command instead, or update the vi alias.

Comment: Does one really need to install macvim? Trying not to install Xcode.

brew install vim --with-lua --HEAD didn't do it either.

Comment: the cp command does not work:
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1401 is a directory (not copied).

Comment: The command `brew install macvim --with-cscope --with-lua --HEAD` gives me an error "invalid option --with-cscope".

Comment: The above command `brew install macvim --with-cscope --with-lua --HEAD` did not work. After reading some FAQs for macvim, all I had to do was to add this line to my .vimrc: `set luadll=/usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.3.5_1/lib/liblua.5.3.dylib` . Note that this path is where `brew install lua` installed it. Your path may differ.

Answer (score 2):

Kevin Lin's answer did not work for me. Using Homebrew and Zsh, this did:

1. `homebrew install vim --with-lua`
2. Putting this in `/.zshrc`:

   `# use brew vim if present
    /usr/local/bin/vim --version > /dev/null 2>&1
    BREW_VIM_INSTALLED=$?

    if [ $BREW_VIM_INSTALLED -eq 0 ]; then

       alias vi="/usr/local/bin/vim"
    fi`

While you are at it, you might want to add `--with-clipboard` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Below steps works fine for me:

1. brew uninstall macvim
2. brew uninstall vim
3. brew install macvim --with-cscope --with-lua --HEAD
4. brew install luajit
5. brew install vim --with-luajit ( I have tried brew install vim --with-lua but that did not work out for me)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in Mac OS X, installing vim with lua support is enough. You just have to be sure that you're running the version you installed.

Run the following command and look for *+lua*

```
vim --version
```

Also check it's the version you compiled.

Comment: grep can look for you: `vim --version | grep +lua`

Answer (score 0):

```
brew update && brew install vim --with-lua
```

Create an alias vim pointing to `/usr/local/bin/vim` (as system vim is still there at /usr/bin/vim). On zsh you can add the following snippet to your .zshrc to create an alias if a brew installed vim is present on the system.

1. Add `/usr/local/bin/vim` into `$PATH` before `/usr/bin`
2. Use brew vim if present

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/vim --version > /dev/null 2>&1 BREW_VIM_INSTALLED=$? if [ $BREW_VIM_INSTALLED -eq 0 ]; then alias vi="/usr/local/bin/vim" fi
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Working Steps:

```
brew update
brew unlink macvim
brew install macvim --with-cscope --with-lua --HEAD
brew unlink vim
brew uninstall vim
brew install vim --with-lua
```

Check all version installed location by `brew info vim`